# Print content page without masterpage fit to the paper

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visual-studio

I need to print out a content page without masterpage. for this I used the below code:

```
<style>
    @media print{
        @page {size: landscape}

        .noPrint {
            display: none;            
        }

        .yesPrint {
            display: block !important;            
        }
    }
</style>
```

Then I set the class "noPrint" to the left and top navigation bars.
When I try to print the page, the navigation bars will diaper as expected but the white space of them remain on the page on the top and left as showed in the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUXco.jpg).

I need to just print the content page with 100% width of the paper(A4) , even if I try to print it out from mobile phone with responsive view.

Comment: Hard to say without your html, one thing you can check is did you put the noPrint on the container? Seems like you put it on the child elements and the container space is still reserved?

Answer (score 0):

@Mick Feller

Here is what I did in masterpage

```
    <!--left-fixed -navigation-->
    <div class="sidebar noPrint" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-collapse">
            <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left" id="cbp-spmenu-s1">   
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                   <asp:TreeView ID="MenuTree" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" BeforeCollapse="MenuTree_TreeNodeCollapsed" BeforeExpand="MenuTree_TreeNodeExpanded">                      
                   </asp:TreeView> 

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--left-fixed -navigation-->
    <!-- header-starts -->
    <div class="sticky-header header-section noPrint">
        <div class="header-left">
            <!--toggle button start-->
            <button id="showLeftPush"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            <!--toggle button end-->
        </div>
    </div>
```